# Reading Test Data from Excel Sheet by using Selenium WebDriver with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am able to read data from excel sheet. However, when I am trying to enter data value from excel sheet into web application it is throwing error message  GetCell is not allowing in the eclipse.

Comment: could you share the code snippet and approach you are using for excel reading would help to provide some answer

Comment: FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream("D:\\D Drive\\SeleniumPractice\\ReadData.xlsx");
   XSSFWorkbook workbook= new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
   XSSFSheet sheet= workbook.getSheetAt(0);
   int rowcount = sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();
   for (int i=0;i<rowcount+1;i++){
      Row Row=sheet.getRow(i);
      for (int j=0;j<Row.getLastCellNum();j++){
      System.out.print(Row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+ " ");
       String Username = sheet.getCell(i,j).getContents();

Comment: getCell(i,j) iam getting red color line.even iam entering get. cell comment is displaying..cell is not displaying.

Comment: Hi Avanthi, please learn how to [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31428139/edit) your own question. You could just post your most recent code there and point out what is going wrong, instead of posting lots of comments with source code on question/answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use below code, it will work.

Java Class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class TestAutomation {
@Test(groups = { "test_proxy" })
public void test_proxy() throws Exception {
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(
                new File("d:\\test.xlsx"));
        // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        // Iterate through each rows one by one
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            // For each row, iterate through all the columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                // Check the cell type and format accordingly
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "t");
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        file.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: ..thanks .I want to read only one value from the excel sheet.

Comment: in for loop place break point once you read the value for particular cell

Comment: If iam using XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);String Username = sheet.getCell(0,1).getContents();

Comment: Y error cmg..If iam giving in XSSF and HSSf format ..y get cell is not identifying.If am giving FileInputStream fs =new FileInputStream("D:\\D Drive\\SeleniumPractice\\TestData.xls");
  Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
  String Username = sheet.getCell(0,1).getContents(); 
  System.out.println(Username);
  String password = sheet.getCell(1,1).getContents();
        System.out.print(password);

Comment: I am getting solution ..If iam using basic format as "HSSF" and "XSSF"..y iam not gettng solution.